# 2D list in Python repeats random number assignments

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, arraylist, reference

Apologies as I'm sure this problem has come up before but none of the examples seem to apply.

I'm trying to create a 2D list (4 by 100) which assigns random values in different ranges in each row.

```
import random
size_of_meadow = 100
no_of_flowers = 100
no_of_flower_types = 3

flower = [[0] * 5] * no_of_flowers

for row in range(no_of_flowers):
    flower[row][0] = random.randint(0, size_of_meadow - 1)  # x coord
    flower[row][1] = random.randint(0, size_of_meadow - 1)  # y coord
    flower[row][2] = random.randint(1, no_of_flower_types)
if random.randint(0, 100) < 5:
    flower[row][3] = 1
else:
    flower[row][3] = 0

print(flower[0][0])
print(flower[0][1])
print(flower[0][2])
print(flower[0][3])
print(" ")
print(flower[1][0])
print(flower[1][1])
print(flower[1][2])
print(flower[1][3])
# Sorry the above isn't in a for loop
```

The outputs just show the same set of numbers for each row of the 2D list...

Output:

```
29
21
2
0

29
21
2
0
```

I'm new to python and I know I must be missing something fundamental, but after a lot of umming and ahhing I haven't figured it out, any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `print('\n'.join([''.join(['{} '.format(item) for item in row]) for row in flower]))` this might also be helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one list that contains 100 times the same list

```
a=[0,0,0]
flower=[a,a,a,a,...]
```

Better solution will be

```
import random

size_of_meadow = 100
no_of_flowers = 100
no_of_flower_types = 3

flower = []

for row in range(no_of_flowers):
  flower.append([random.randint(0, size_of_meadow-1),
      random.randint(0, size_of_meadow-1),
      random.randint(1, no_of_flower_types),
      1 if random.randint(0, 100) < 5 else 0])

print(flower[0][0])
print(flower[0][1])
print(flower[0][2])
print(flower[0][3])
print(" ")
print(flower[1][0])
print(flower[1][1])
print(flower[1][2])
print(flower[1][3])
# Sorry the above isn't in a for loop
```

However flower generator would be even better

Comment: This is great and produced the results I wanted. I'm still don't entirely understand the mistake I was making but will move forward using this method in future.

Answer (score 3):

By using `[[0] * 5] * no_of_flowers` you are creating 100 references to the same list. This means there is **ONLY ONE ROW** in the memory.

When you modify a row, if affects the row in memory, and since all other "rows" refer to it, they will simply use the list in memory which is up-to-date.

**To avoid this scenario, you could use:**

```
flower = [[0 for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(no_of_flowers)]
```

---

You could find an [example and explanation in wtfpython](https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython#-a-tic-tac-toe-where-x-wins-in-the-first-attempt):

```
# Let's initialize a row
row = [""]*3 #row i['', '', '']
# Let's make a board
board = [row]*3
```

Output:

```
>>> board
[['', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', '']]
>>> board[0]
['', '', '']
>>> board[0][0]
''
>>> board[0][0] = "X"
>>> board
[['X', '', ''], ['X', '', ''], ['X', '', '']]
```

**Explanation:**

When we initialize `row` variable, this visualization explains what happens in the memory.

[image]

And when the `board` is initialized by multiplying the `row`, this is what happens inside the memory (each of the elements `board[0]`, `board[1]` and `board[2]` is a reference to the same list referred by `row`)

[image]

We can avoid this scenario here by not using `row` variable to generate `board`. (Asked in [this](https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython/issues/68) issue).

```
>>> board = [['']*3 for _ in range(3)]
>>> board[0][0] = "X"
>>> board
[['X', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', '']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey @Lee has it correct but let me elaborate

```
>>> flower = [[0] * 5] * 100
>>> flower[0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> flower[1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> id(flower[0])
4354853640
>>> id(flower[1])
4354853640
```

Here you can see that each sub list will point to the same location in memory

I would use this method:

```
flower = [[None for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(no_of_flowers)] 

>>> id(flower[0])
4354853832
>>> id(flower[1])
4354854600
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but why are all of them pointing to the same position? I actually expected [[0] * 5] * 100 to run the same way as your code.

Comment: This answer produced the output I wanted from just changing the one line of code which is great.

Comment: @epsilonmajorquezero when you run `[0] * 5` it creates one list `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` and then the `* 100` makes a list that has the sub list point to each 100 positions. The list comp actually re-runs in each iteration creating new elements

Comment: @bison that made the problem really clear, thanks for the explanation

Comment: Yeah, I see that's what it must be doing according to behaviour but then the behaviour is not really consistent: first [0] * 5 which creates a list of 5 zeroes (which are not the same location in memory) but then this list multiplied again does point to the same position.